# Operands could not be broadcast together error when trying to construct an ndarray as a function of two other ndarrays with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I create two numpy arrays. I want to create a third array as a function of each element in these two arrays. I attempted the following, but it doesn't work.

```
X = np.arange(-180., 180., 1.)
Y = X
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = np.ndarray([func(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(X, Y)])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,360) (2,)
```

In case it's relevant to the solution, the purpose of these three arrays is to construct a 3D plot in matplotlib:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Comment: Running your code with `func` being a simple addtion function, I got a `ValueError: sequence too large; must be smaller than 32`

Comment: Where is the error.  Also show us some intermediate values.  It should be easy to debug if you look step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Why use a ndarray for `Z`, instead of a (360, 360) `np.array` ?

Replace this line

```
Z = np.ndarray([func(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(X, Y)])
```

with

```
Z = np.array([func(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(X, Y)])
```

See the difference between `np.array()` and `np.ndarray()`

```
t1 = np.ndarray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

t1.shape
Out[39]: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

t2 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

t2.shape
Out[41]: (5,)
```